# What will happen if we will be able to produce a quark-gluon plasma and the we cool it down?

Tags: plasma-physics, quark-gluon-plasma

Lets assume that we can produce a quark-gluon plasma and then we try to cool it down, what will happen to it ?

Comment: It will disintegrate into hadrons (baryons and mesons). These will fly away and decay into stable particles.

Answer (score 1):

You get the quark-anti quark (meson) and triple quark baryon (or triple antiquark i.e. anti-baryon) bound states (where the quarks/anti-quarks interact with gluons).

At a collider experiment, there is no need to "actively cool" the quark gluon plasma, this happens automatically and one sees the hadrons (mesons/baryons/anti-baryons) in the detector.

In the evolution of the early universe, this is what started the ["hadron epoch"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Big_Bang#Hadron_epoch).

See e.g. also http://home.web.cern.ch/about/physics/heavy-ions-and-quark-gluon-plasma

Comment: I heard that quarks and gluons must be bounded together  in normal condition..if so ,when we cool down this plasma these fundamental particles must return bounded to form protons,neutrons ecc ecc or i am missing something?

Comment: yes, exactly. Protons and neutrons are baryons (but in principle other baryons could be formed as well but these are typically short lived as are the mesons).

Comment: Ok so,i a certain sense we can say that we are able to re-create matter from foundamental particles? Or in another words to re-create the right conditions where baryonic matter took place after the big bang right?

Comment: Wonderful..this could teach us so many things about the origin of matter in the universe

Comment: yes, the purpose of colliders is to have energies (or better: energy densities) similar to those shortly after the big bang (in the lab) to study the relevant physical processes which led to the formation of the universe we know today.

Comment: Just for make everything more clear : If we take normal matter (i.e. not anti-matter )and we make quark-gluon plasma with it when the latter cools down we can see the formation of also anti-baryons in the process or only baryon and mesons ?

Comment: yes, the quark gluon plasma also contains antiquarks. Even an ordinary proton contains anti quarks in what is called the ['sea'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Sea_quarks). These are created when a gluon splits into a quark/anti-quark pair and normally 'recombine' quickly but they can interact with the quarks/gluons/antiquarks of another proton in a collision. So even if no quark gluon plasma is created in a particular proton-proton (or Lead ion-Lead ion) collision, antiparticles (such as antiprotons) can be produced.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13304/discussion-between-user27494-and-andre-holzner)

Comment: so gluons contains quark and anti quark pairs..it seems there's no way to create matter witouth creating anti matter